# No me carga la Funcion, pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, game, motor-de-juego

Anteriormente había hecho una publicación, donde me expresé mal y no explique cual era mi problema, así que ahora voy a intentar ser extenso y explicar lo que me sucede.

Estoy haciendo un juego para aprender en pygame, es un juego super sencillo, donde mi idea es crear un juego, donde sos un granjero que intentas recolectar monedas. sin sprites me funcionaba bien, es más. se podia jugar, el problema fue cuando le puse la clase "granjero" con sus atributos; Así esta;

```
    import pygame
import tamaño
class Granjero:
    def __init__(self):
        self.imagen = pygame.image.load("juegos/imagenes/granjero.png")
        self.sprites = []
        self.recortar_sprites()
        self.sprite_actual = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(5, 120, 30, 43)
        self.direccion = "abajo"
        
    def recortar_sprites(self):
        #Cargar imagen con los sprites
        sprites_image = pygame.image.load("juegos/imagenes/granjero.png")

        #Obtener sub-superficie del primer sprite (caminando hacia arriba)
        sprite_arriba1 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(0,129 ,30, 43))
        sprite_arriba2 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(41, 129, 30, 43))
        sprite_arriba3 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(86.21, 129, 30, 43))
        sprite_arriba4 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(133, 129, 30, 43))
        #sprite_arriba5 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(174, 129, 30, 43))
        #sprite_arriba6 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(220, 129, 30, 43))
        #Obtener sub-superficie del segundo sprite (caminando hacia arriba)
        sprite_derecha1 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(0, 86, 30, 43))
        sprite_derecha2 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(41, 86, 30, 43))
        sprite_derecha3 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(86, 86, 30, 43))
        sprite_derecha4 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(133, 86, 30, 43))
        #sprite_derecha5 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(174, 86, 30, 43))
        #sprite_derecha6 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(220, 86, 30, 43))
        
        sprite_izquierda1 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(0, 44, 30, 43))
        sprite_izquierda2 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(41, 44, 30, 43))
        sprite_izquierda3 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(86, 44, 30, 43))
        sprite_izquierda4 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(133, 44, 30, 43))
        #sprite_izquierda5 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(174, 44, 30, 43))
        #sprite_izquierda6 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(220, 44, 30, 43))

        sprite_abajo1 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(0, 0, 30, 43))
        sprite_abajo2 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(41, 0, 30, 43)) 
        sprite_abajo3 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(86, 0, 30, 43))
        sprite_abajo4 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(133, 0, 30, 43))
        #sprite_abajo5 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(174, 0, 30, 43))
        #sprite_abajo6 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(220, 0, 30, 43))

        self.sprites.append(sprite_arriba1)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_arriba2)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_arriba3)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_arriba4)
        #self.sprites.append(sprite_arriba5)
        #self.sprites.append(sprite_arriba6)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_derecha1)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_derecha2)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_derecha3)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_derecha4)
        #self.sprites.append(sprite_derecha5)
        #self.sprites.append(sprite_derecha6)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_izquierda1)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_izquierda2)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_izquierda3)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_izquierda4)
        #self.sprites.append(sprite_izquierda5)
        #self.sprites.append(sprite_izquierda6)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_abajo1)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_abajo2)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_abajo3)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_abajo4)
        #self.sprites.append(sprite_abajo5)
        #self.sprites.append(sprite_abajo6)


    def update(self):
        self.sprite_actual += 1
        if self.sprite_actual >= len(self.sprites):
            self.sprite_actual = 0
            tamaño.ventana.blit(self.sprites[self.sprite_actual], (self.x, self.y))
```

Tuve que quitar partes del codigo, porque me daba error, no sabia lo que era, así que opte por lo más sencillo, sacarlo del codigo comentandolo, jejeje.

Bueno, el problema no es ese, el problema es en el archivo "principal.py" donde tengo la función menú, función creditos, función gameover y función "jugar".

Cuando le doy ejecutar, funciona de lo más bien, es más, hasta se escucha la música y todo, te podes mover.
[image: Cuando le doy a ejecutar, funciona de lo más bien]

El problema viene cuando le doy a "inciar jugar", ahí es cuando empieza el fallo, ya que cuando lo presiono, se me tranca la pantalla del juego y se queda sin responder.

La verdad pienso que es un problema del sprite o del fondo, tambien podria ser directamente el problema de la funcion menu cuando le doy a jugar, no sé, pueden ser muchas cosas, así que dejo  el codigo,  expliquenme y ayudenme a arreglarlo, soy nuevo y quiero aprender

Solo dejaré el def menu y el def jugar, pienso que lo otro es irrelevante

```
 import pygame
import random
import sys
import tamaño


pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("Tu hermana 1")
def menu():
    pygame.mixer.music.load("juegos/musica/hola1.mp3")
    fondonivel = pygame.image.load("juegos/imagenes/fondomenu.jpg")

    # Reproducir música del menú en loop
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)

    
    opcion = 1
    fuente = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
    

    while True:
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    opcion -= 1
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    opcion += 1
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    if opcion == 1:
                        # Iniciar juego
                        jugar()
                    elif opcion == 2:
                        # Mostrar opciones
                        creditos()
                    elif opcion == 3:
                        # Salir del juego
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
        tamaño.ventana.blit(fondonivel,(0,0))
        opciones = ["Iniciar juego", "creditos", "Salir"]
        y = 50
        for i, texto in enumerate(opciones):
            if i + 1 == opcion:
                color = (255, 0, 0)
            else:
                color = (255, 255, 255)
            opcion_texto = fuente.render(texto, 1, color)
            text_rect = opcion_texto.get_rect()
            text_rect.center = ((tamaño.Ancho / 2), (tamaño.Altura / 2)+y)
            tamaño.ventana.blit(opcion_texto, text_rect)
            y +=50
        pygame.display.update()


def jugar():
    from granjero import Granjero
    granjero= Granjero()
    
    fondojuego = pygame.image.load("juegos/imagenes/fondonivel.jpg")
    tamaño.ventana.blit(fondojuego,(0,0))
    tamaño.ventana.blit(granjero.sprites[granjero.sprite_actual], granjero.rect)
    pygame.mixer.music.load("juegos/musica/bebe.ogg")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)

    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    reloj = pygame.time.Clock()

    tamaño_x=20
    tamaño_y=20
    
    velocidad_x= 1
    velocidad_y=1
    velocidad_x_enemigo=1
    velocidad_y_enemigo=1


    food_rect = pygame.Rect(random.randint(10, 1200), random.randint(10, 600), tamaño_x,tamaño_y)
    enemigo=  pygame.Rect(random.randint(10, 1200), random.randint(10, 600), tamaño_x,tamaño_y)

    puntos = 0
    vida= 10

    fuente = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)


    while True:
    
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.unicode == "w":
                    granjero.rect.y -= 5+velocidad_y
                    granjero.cambiar_animacion("arriba")
                    
                elif event.unicode == "s":
                    granjero.rect.y += 5+velocidad_y
                    granjero.cambiar_animacion("abajo")
                    
                elif event.unicode == "a":
                    granjero.rect.x -= 5+velocidad_x
                    granjero.cambiar_animacion("izquierda")
                   
                elif event.unicode == "d":
                    granjero.rect.x += 5+velocidad_x
                    granjero.cambiar_animacion("derecha")
          
            pygame.display.flip()
            tamaño.ventana.blit(fondojuego, (0, 0))
            tamaño.ventana.blit(granjero.sprites[granjero.sprite_actual], granjero.rect)
            pygame.display.update()
        if granjero.left < 0 or granjero.right > 1200:
            velocidad_x = -velocidad_x
        if granjero.top < 20 or granjero.bottom > 600:
            velocidad_y = -velocidad_y
        if enemigo.left < 0 or enemigo.right > 1200:
            velocidad_x_enemigo = -velocidad_x_enemigo
        if enemigo.top < 20 or enemigo.bottom > 600:
            velocidad_y_enemigo = -velocidad_y_enemigo  
        enemigo.x += velocidad_x_enemigo
        enemigo.y += velocidad_y_enemigo
        
        if granjero.colliderect(food_rect):
        
            granjero.width += 5
            granjero.height += 5
        
            food_rect = pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, 450), random.randint(0, 450), tamaño_x,tamaño_y)
            puntos +=1
        if granjero.colliderect(enemigo):
        
            
        
            enemigo.x = random.randint(0, 1200)
            enemigo.y = random.randint(10, 600)
            
            enemigo = pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, 1200), random.randint(0, 600), tamaño_x,tamaño_y)
            vida -= 1

       
        if vida == 0:
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            Gameover()
        

        
        tamaño.ventana.blit(puntos_texto, (10, 10))
        tamaño.ventana.blit(vida_texto, (200, 10))
        pygame.display.update()
        
        pygame.draw.rect(tamaño.ventana, (255, 0, 0), food_rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(tamaño.ventana, (255, 100, 200), enemigo)
        tamaño.ventana.blit(fondojuego, (0, 0))
        tamaño.ventana.blit(granjero.sprites[granjero.sprite_actual], granjero.rect)


        puntos_texto = fuente.render("Puntos: " + str(puntos), 1, (255, 255, 255))
        vida_texto= fuente.render("Vida:"  +str(vida),1,(255, 255, 255) )
        tamaño.ventana.blit(puntos_texto, (10, 10))
        tamaño.ventana.blit(vida_texto, (200, 10))
        pygame.display.update()

        reloj.tick(130)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Hola @Lucas Martinez, primero un consejo, no hagas otra pregunta, edita la que ya has hecho (con el botón editar), te van a saltar al cuello, jaja, te recomiendo hacer el tour en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, para saber como preguntar, de esa manera te evitas votos negativos, y/o el cierre de tu pregunta... con respecto a tu código, yo no soy programador de python, pero me ha llamado la atención, que dentro de la función **jugar**, tienes un **import**, insisto, solo uso python para cosas simples, pero juraría que **está muy mal**, los import van al principio del archivo...

Comment: Para que tu publicación se visualize bien (si ese código comentado), copia tu código entero, he identalo 4 espacios, hay una herramienta especifica para ello **{}**, en la cabecera.

Comment: @MarcePuente los import en Python pueden aparecer en cualquier parte del programa, pero por convención y conveniencia se hacen arriba de todo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @Dante, la verdad me sorprende, jamas vi un código asií, pero bue, siempre se aprende!!!

Comment: Es que yo siempre los puse al principio, pero cuando estaba programando el juego, me daba error, porque se creaba un bucle infinito, así que lo que hice fue eso. luego hice un archivo, para guardar los valores de las variables importantes, como el tamaño de la pantalla.  mi problema radica en que cuando le doy a inciar el juego, me deja de responder y la verdad no se porque es

Comment: Logré encontrarle la forma, hice una copia de seguridad y una copia, en la copa me concentré en el juego y al parecer anda funcionando